# Understanding MATLAB's `fmincg` optimization function

Tags: optimization, conjugate-gradient

I'm researching numerical optimization. Recently I've come across a variant of a conjugate gradient method named `fmincg`.

The function is written in MATLAB and is used in the famous Andrew Ng's course on Machine Learning on Coursera. According to the copyright notice, `fmincg` was written by [Carl Edward Rasmussen](http://learning.eng.cam.ac.uk/carl/).

You can find the full text of `fmincg` on the MATLAB [file exchange](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42770-logistic-regression-with-regularization-used-to-classify-hand-written-digits/content/Logistic%20Regression%20with%20regularisation/fmincg.m).

I'm trying to figure out the algorithm. The structure is quite straightforward as it closely follows the reference text I'm currently using (Numerical Optimization, Nocedal & Wright).

However I'm having a harder time figuring out the details of the line search procedure.
Specifically, here's the code for the line search loop:

```
while 1
while ((f2 > f1+z1*RHO*d1) | (d2 > -SIG*d1)) & (M > 0) 
  limit = z1;                                         % tighten the bracket
  if f2 > f1
    z2 = z3 - (0.5*d3*z3*z3)/(d3*z3+f2-f3);                 % quadratic fit
  else
    A = 6*(f2-f3)/z3+3*(d2+d3);                                 % cubic fit
    B = 3*(f3-f2)-z3*(d3+2*d2);
    z2 = (sqrt(B*B-A*d2*z3*z3)-B)/A;       % numerical error possible - ok!
  end
  if isnan(z2) | isinf(z2)
    z2 = z3/2;                  % if we had a numerical problem then bisect
  end
  z2 = max(min(z2, INT*z3),(1-INT)*z3);  % don't accept too close to limits
  z1 = z1 + z2;                                           % update the step
  X = X + z2*s;
  [f2 df2] = eval(argstr);
  M = M - 1; i = i + (length<0);                           % count epochs?!
  d2 = df2'*s;
  z3 = z3-z2;                    % z3 is now relative to the location of z2
end
if f2 > f1+z1*RHO*d1 | d2 > -SIG*d1
  break;                                                % this is a failure
elseif d2 > SIG*d1
  success = 1; break;                                             % success
elseif M == 0
  break;                                                          % failure
end
A = 6*(f2-f3)/z3+3*(d2+d3);                      % make cubic extrapolation
B = 3*(f3-f2)-z3*(d3+2*d2);
z2 = -d2*z3*z3/(B+sqrt(B*B-A*d2*z3*z3));        % num. error possible - ok!
if ~isreal(z2) | isnan(z2) | isinf(z2) | z2 < 0   % num prob or wrong sign?
  if limit < -0.5                               % if we have no upper limit
    z2 = z1 * (EXT-1);                 % the extrapolate the maximum amount
  else
    z2 = (limit-z1)/2;                                   % otherwise bisect
  end
elseif (limit > -0.5) & (z2+z1 > limit)          % extraplation beyond max?
  z2 = (limit-z1)/2;                                               % bisect
elseif (limit < -0.5) & (z2+z1 > z1*EXT)       % extrapolation beyond limit
  z2 = z1*(EXT-1.0);                           % set to extrapolation limit
elseif z2 < -z3*INT
  z2 = -z3*INT;
elseif (limit > -0.5) & (z2 < (limit-z1)*(1.0-INT))   % too close to limit?
  z2 = (limit-z1)*(1.0-INT);
end
f3 = f2; d3 = d2; z3 = -z2;                  % set point 3 equal to point 2
z1 = z1 + z2; X = X + z2*s;                      % update current estimates
[f2 df2] = eval(argstr);
M = M - 1; i = i + (length<0);                             % count epochs?!
d2 = df2'*s; 
end
```

I would like to understand the following:

- before the loop, the point 3 is initialized as: `f3 = f1; d3 = d1; z3 = -z1;` and the comment says `Save point 0`. But why does he set `z3 = -z1`?
   (in case someone's wondering, no, it's - apparently - not a mistake because 1. the algo works and 2. I've tried running it with `z3 = z1` and it breaks)
- how the author is using the Wolfe conditions and its constants?
- interpolation / extrapolation. Where do the equations he's using come from? E.g.:

  `A = 6*(f2-f3)/z3+3*(d2+d3); 
   B = 3*(f3-f2)-z3*(d3+2*d2);
   z2 = -d2*z3*z3/(B+sqrt(B*B-A*d2*z3*z3));`
- what's going on in the if-else checks that involve the `limit` variable? Note that before entering the `while 1`, he set `limit = -1`

**EDIT:**
added one more question to the bullet list

Comment: I think the Wolfe conditions are (the negation of) the loop test `(f2 > f1+z1*RHO*d1) | (d2 > -SIG*d1)`, but I can't readily suggest anything for your other questions.

Comment: yes, that was the easy one :) What's not very clear to me is why he makes the other check `elseif d2 > SIG*d1, success = 1; break;` which I cannot relate to the literature

Comment: Yeah :) I didn't see the second one, I think it's the curvature condition with absolute signs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfe_conditions#Strong_Wolfe_condition_on_curvature) (because `d2 < -SIG*d1` from the first if-guard) and means it's right to terminate the line search. If I may say, whoever wrote this had a page full of notes in front of them, and the code isn't written to be read without those notes.

Comment: I think it's `z3 = -z1` because it says later in a comment that "z3 is now relative to the location of z2", so point 1 is at coordinate $-z_1$ relative to point 2 at $z_1$.

Comment: That's a good point. It is actually checking the absolute value of `d2` as part of the strong Wolfe-Powell condition. This should more or less solve question number 2!